# Better way to determine when users are active?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which contains information about users who post messages to my website.  The table is named `logs` and has the following records: `id, epoch, username, msg` (epoch is a unix epoch of when they posted, msg is the message posted)

I have decided to divide the day into 4 segments, 6 hours each (0-5, 6-11, 12-17, 18-23).

I want to determine the percentage of posts that the user makes during each of these segments.

Is there any nice way that I can do this with only one sql query? It would take forever if I had to make 4 queries like below per username.

```
SELECT count( num )
FROM `logs`
WHERE username = 'bob'
AND from_unixtime( epoch )
BETWEEN date_sub( now( ) , INTERVAL 1 week )
AND now( )
AND hour( from_unixtime( epoch ) )
BETWEEN 0
AND 5
```

The above query tells me how many posts bob has made between the hours 0 and 5, from the past week.  This feels horribly inefficient, because it would probably be better if the query could just load all of bobs posts, get all the data I need, and then return that; instead of having to load his posts 5 different times (#1 to get total posts, #2/3/4/5 to get his posts during a specific hour range)

My goal is to get all the posts bob has made in one query, divided by the different times of the day (i.e. between hour 0 and 5, hour 6 and 11, hour 12 and 17, hour 18 and 23).  I can then divide this individual information by bobs total posts and for instance see that bob posts 80% of his posts during hour 6 and 11, etc

This way, I can find out exactly when bob is active

Comment: Is your solution entirely in PHP and MySQL, or is there a user interface in HTML/Javascript?

Comment: Can you do the hour value integer-div 6, to give a 0-3 segment number? This could be the basis of a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Yes, I'm going to use HTML/Javascript with this.  And yeah, I can split the hours by 6, that works too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
create table buckets(int low, int hi);

insert into buckets values(0, 5), (6, 11), (12, 17), (18, 23);

SELECT `low`, `hi`, count( num )
FROM `logs`, `buckets`
WHERE username = 'bob'
AND from_unixtime( epoch )
BETWEEN date_sub( now( ) , INTERVAL 1 week )
AND now( )
AND hour( from_unixtime( epoch ) )
BETWEEN `buckets`.`low`
AND `buckets`.`hi`
GROUP BY `buckets`.`low`;
```

If you want the same query to also give you stats for the entire day, insert `(0, 23)` into buckets in addition to other four values.

UPDATE: as halfer pointed out in the comments, with your time intervals you can also just group by `hour div 6`:

```sql
SELECT hour( from_unixtime( epoch ) ) div 6 * 6, hour( from_unixtime( epoch ) ) div 6 * 6 + 5, count( num )
FROM `logs`
WHERE username = 'bob'
AND from_unixtime( epoch )
BETWEEN date_sub( now( ) , INTERVAL 1 week )
AND now( )
GROUP BY hour( from_unixtime( epoch ) ) div 6;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would instead use something like this:

```
select count(msg) as TotalMsg,
    sum(CASE WHEN (epoch MOD 86400)<21600 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Period_1,
    sum(CASE WHEN (epoch MOD 86400)>=21600 AND (epoch MOD 86400)<43200 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Period_2,
    sum(CASE WHEN (epoch MOD 86400)>=43200 AND (epoch MOD 86400)<64800 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Period_3,
    sum(CASE WHEN (epoch MOD 86400)>=64800 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Period_4
from logs
    where username='bob';

# 86400 = seconds in 24 hours
```